# Merge Replication Status

Tags: merge, replication, database-replication, merge-replication

I was working on a merge replication on SQL SERVER 2012. I have one central server with the publication and distribution configured on the same machine.I have another three machines with SQL SERVER 2012 as subscribers. The replication is working fine, however, what I want to see is the how much of the data on the central server is about to be merged to the subscribers? Is there a tool that will help me to see the data that is merged so far and data which is not yet merged?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides a stored procedure [sp_showpendingchanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186795.aspx) which will provide an approximation of the pending changes that need to be replicated.  Note that this stored procedure does not work well [when the subscription database name is the same as the publication database name](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/repltalk/archive/2015/03/04/repltalk-quicktip-showing-pending-changes-for-merge-replication-using-sp-showpendingchanges.aspx).

You can also run a [data validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151251.aspx), use the [tablediff utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx), or use SQL Data Compare to determine how out of sync you are.

Comment: Brandon Thank you again. very helpful. I am exploring the one which suits me.